# Adding image to node in Forest

Tags: graphics, pdftex, forest

I would like to take a Forest like so:

**Forest:**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  styleA/.style={top color=green!20, bottom color=green!50},
  styleB/.style={top color=white, bottom color=red!20},
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    align=center,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
  },
  forked edges,
  [Blablabla
     [Blablabla,styleA]
     [Blablabla,styleA]
     [Blablabla
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla,styleB]
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla,styleB]
                 [Blablabla]
              ]
           ]
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                 ]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                    ]
                 ]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                 ]]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
           ]
        ]
     ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

And embed add images to the nodes/inside the nodes like so

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Those don't appear to be inside the nodes. If they shouldn't affect the spacing, use `tikz+=` to add nodes on top containing the images. If they really should be inside the nodes, then you can just add them within the relevant nodes wherever appropriate.

Comment: @cfr I can settle for fully inside. can you give a MWE with an example as I don't see how tikz+= can be used to embed a standard image file.

Comment: You don't need `tikz+` if you put it inside the node, but only if you don't. I'll try to give an example with `tikz+` in a bit if nobody else answers first.

Comment: @cfr I don't understand, you mean just drop an `includegraphics{...}` command inside the node?

Comment: Yes. I assume it would work. You might need to use `{blablabla \includegraphics[<options>]{filename}}` but it should work, I'd think. It is just a TikZ node at the end of the day.

Comment: @cfr was `{blablabla...}` a typo or do you mean I should switch from using square brackets `[blablabla \includegraphics{}]` to using curly brackets `{blablabla \includegraphics{}}`

Comment: I mean you need the curly brackets to protect the contents of the node. You still have the square brackets, but inside them you have `{...}` rather than just `...`. See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either add the image within the node or add the image in its own node after the tree is drawn either directly or using `tikz`. Either way, you can do this either for specific nodes within the tree or for all nodes assigned a certain style. The image can be specified as part of the style or it can be determined when the style is used.

The following examples present most of these possibilities.

The simplest approach is just to add the image in the node content. For example:

```
    [Blablabla\\\includegraphics{info},styleA]
```

will add the `info` image from the `notes` package on a line below the node text `Blablabla`.

If we need to pass `\includegraphics` an optional argument, we need to protect it from Forest's bracket parser:

```
    [Blablabla  {\includegraphics[scale=.5]{warn}},styleA]
```

This can also be added using a style. For example, we could adapt `styleB` to include the `hand` image:

```
  styleB/.style={%
    top color=white,
    bottom color=red!20,
    delay={%
      content/.wrap value={##1\\{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{hand}}}
    }
  },
```

Then our tree will look like this:

[image: images in nodes]

Alternatively, we could add the images in their own nodes after the tree is drawn. One way to do this is to use Forest's `tikz` or `tikz+` key. For example, we might define an `add icon` style to do this conveniently as follows:

```
  add icon/.style={%
    !u.s sep+=5pt,
    tikz+={\node [draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=white] at (.south west) {\includegraphics [height=\baselineskip]{#1}};}
  },
```

Then we can write

```
    [Blablabla, add icon=warn,styleA]
    [Blablabla, add icon=info,styleA]
```

to add the specified image to the designated node. Again, this could also be used in a modified `styleB`, for example.

```
styleB/.style={%
    top color=white,
    bottom color=red!20,
    add icon=hand,
  },
```

Then our tree will look like this:

[image: badge-style addition of images to nodes]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  styleA/.style={top color=green!20, bottom color=green!50},
  styleB/.style={%
    top color=white,
    bottom color=red!20,
    delay={%
      content/.wrap value={##1\\{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{hand}}}
    }
  },
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    align=center,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
  },
  forked edges,
  [Blablabla
    [Blablabla  {\includegraphics[scale=.5]{warn}},styleA]
    [Blablabla\\\includegraphics{info},styleA]
     [Blablabla
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla,styleB]
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla,styleB]
                 [Blablabla]
              ]
           ]
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                 ]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                    ]
                 ]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                 ]]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
           ]
        ]
     ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  add icon/.style={%
    !u.s sep+=5pt,
    tikz+={\node [draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=white] at (.south west) {\includegraphics [height=\baselineskip]{#1}};}
  },
  styleA/.style={top color=green!20, bottom color=green!50},
  styleB/.style={%
    top color=white,
    bottom color=red!20,
    add icon=hand,
  },
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    align=center,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
    inner sep=5pt
  },
  forked edges,
  [Blablabla
    [Blablabla, add icon=warn,styleA]
    [Blablabla, add icon=info,styleA]
     [Blablabla
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla]
        [Blablabla
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla,styleB]
              [Blablabla]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla,styleB]
                 [Blablabla]
              ]
           ]
           [Blablabla
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla]
                    [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                 ]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla
                    [Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla[Blablabla][Blablabla]]
                    ]
                 ]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
              [Blablabla
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                       [Blablabla]
                 ]]
                 [Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla[Blablabla
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                             [Blablabla]
                 ]]]]
              ]
           ]
        ]
     ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an amazing answer. However, I think I am running into problems because I am on windows (not my choice) and the backslash is causing problems. I switched to global paths as `..\..\images` was causing problems

Comment: You may need forward slashes - even on Windows. But that's a different question and, frankly, I'm not a good person to ask. I know almost nothing (as little as I can manage to get away with) about Windows ....