# tikz tree with images

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to do a tree in latex, with images in the nodes. I've been trying with the normal tree drawing procedure, but the images I want at the nodes messes everything up.

Help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code that is messed up (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). Usually there is no problem when placing `\includegraphics` inside a node.

Comment: Besides what gernot said, take a loook at the [`forest`](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) package it's much *much* better than Ti*k*Z from drawing trees. Possibly related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305380/adding-image-to-node-in-forest

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos "forest ... is much better than TikZ" is a bit contradictory given that `forest` is just a thin layer on top of `tikz`.

Comment: Quote the whole sentence ("forest ... much better than Ti*k*Z **for drawing trees**"), then it makes more sense... `;)`

Comment: Please do not ask the exact same question twice. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338749/drawing-a-tree-with-images-in-latex

Comment: @gernot 'Ti*k*Z is much better than PGF' is a bit contradictory given that `tikz` is just a thin layer on top of `pgf`. Forest is much more powerful and flexible, although it is of course true that you could theoretically do exactly the same without it e.g. by essentially writing an alternative to Forest which did the same thing. Likewise, you could dispense with LaTeX or plain or ConTeXt and use only the lower level TeX stuff.

Comment: Including images in nodes: `node {\includegraphics[width=length>]{my-image}`. Image should be in format supported by your way of document compilation. For more particular answer you need to provide small complete document, which will show what you like to obtain.

Comment: @cfr @Zarko The context is that we have no clue what @Jens is actually using for constructing his tree, other than that he'd like to do the tree in latex and that he has tried *the normal tree drawing procedure*, whatever this may be. There is no indication that he uses `tikz`, `pstricks`, `forest`, whatever.

Comment: @gernot, not entirely true, he tagged {tikz-pgf}. To me this is indication enough that the OP's using some Ti*k*Z based method. Also, noting the "normal procedure" part I'd guess is the `tree` library which `forest` is the perfect replacement, hence my comment.

Comment: @gernot So? My comment was a response to your claim that the assertion that Forest was better at drawing trees was `a  bit` contradictory because Forest is Ti*k*Z-based. My point was that the claim is clearly wrong: that A is built from B does not make the claim that A is better than B for purpose P in anyway contradictory or even give any reason to think it false. (And GZS is quite right given the tag. Though the question is not really answerable in its current form as we have no idea what the problem is.)

Comment: @gernot You can only ping one person at a time. Probably the system told you this when you tried to ping 2 people at once.

Comment: @cfr I still pay too little attention to the tags, thanks for pointing that out. And you (and  Guilherme) are also basically right regarding the advantage of forest over tikz. Your tree below would be possible but cumbersome with tikz alone.

Comment: @gernot Yes. I think that's what I was trying to say :-).

Answer (score 8):

I think I ought not answer this question. Moreover, I think my answer very unlikely to help you. However, it is kind of fun to put a bunch of existing images into a Forest tree. And, hey, maybe somebody sometime will even find a use for this.

Anyway, here's a Forest version. It uses Forest's `edges` library which provides the `forked edges` style.

The idea is that you put the name of the relevant image into each node. If you need to pass any options to `\includegraphics`, you pass them via the Forest option `graphics`.

Here's my tree:

[image: Forest with images]

The duck is courtesy of Paulo. The lion is, of course, the CTAN/TUG logo. The donkey is a modified version of an openclipart.org image by frankes (https://openclipart.org/detail/214238/donkey-coloured), exported to Ti*k*Z via Inkscape. The cat, tram and cauldron are mine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  declare toks={graphics}{},
}
\begin{forest}
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={\includegraphics[#2]{#1}}{content()}{graphics()},
    },
    where={isodd(n_children())}{calign=child, calign child/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{int((n_children()+1)/2)}}{},
  },
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    l sep'+=30mm,
    s sep'+=10mm,
    fork sep'+=10mm,
    edge={line width=2.5pt},
  },
  [cath-gadael-chartref
    [cath
      [asyn]
      [duck]
      [ctanlion, graphics={scale=1.5}]
    ]
    [trolley-bws, graphics={scale=8}
      [cauldron]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AlanMunn I use it to illustrate various 'trolley problems' when teaching trolleyology. (I can't now remember if I got that word from somebody or made it up. At any rate, somebody needed to invent it.) But I turned it into a bus for TeX SE. (That is, I called it a 'bus' rather than a 'tram' or a 'trolley'.) The only trouble is, I have an issue with scale. It turns out my buses/trams would make good cat toys, albeit a bit on the minute side of tiny.

Comment: Interesting to see where a sparse two-line posting and an absent OP may lead ;-) Great.